# I may have a keylogger on my desktop, but am unsure

Tags: windows-10, security, virus, keylogger

I recently discovered one of my online accounts had been hacked, nothing major yet, but I'm concerned I may have a keylogger on my Windows 10 desktop. It stirred me into a panic and I immediately ran a full scan with my Kaspersky AV, and also downloaded Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, and scanned my PC with that. Both finished and told me my computer was all clear, but when I checked my task manager I saw a process I've never seen before. I immediately checked my other two Windows 10 desktops and verified that this process was no present on them.

The process is called `osrss` and it's under Windows processes, of which I have 80 running. When I go to view the file location, it is stored in:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost
```

Why it generated such alarm for me is because the only thing that was recently downloaded to my desktop is some game called `Old School Runescape`.  I figured that would mean OSRS? But if that is the case, why is it running under windows processes if it is not a virus?

Any and all help providing information to `osrss` process, and the reliability of two seperate virus scans would greatly appreciated.

Comment: according to this site, http://runescape.salmoneus.net/forums/topic/206013-does-rs-cause-viruses/ Runescape runs things from the Windows folder in the background to make loading faster, so not an immediate cause for concern if your virus scans say you are clean. Do a root kit scan if you are still concerned

Answer (score 1):

Bleeping Computer recognizes this process: `OSRSS.EXE` as an [undesirable program (PUP)](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/startups/OSRSS.exe-12370.html).

So, it is recommended that you remove it from your system, but first, to be sure of this, I suggest you to download [System Explorer Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/system_explorer_portable), this is a very good alternative to Windows Task Manager and can provide you with more information about this file before making a decision.

After running the tool, go to `Processes` tab, search for the suspicious file, then right click and select `File Check`. This will send the file to [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/) where you can have a better idea of it (If it is a malware or not), see the image for a better reference.

[image: system explorer on microsoft windows]

Hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

OSRSS files, and the Folder itself, are part of Windows Updating itself, and deal with any 'failed updates', (as when I stopped an "Update" downloading as didn't want/need it). I deleted osrss .dll files, two 'applications', and the Folder in Windows itself, (you CAN after 'taking control' of it), and, possibly not due to this I know, my desktop seems to run a little faster again.
You certainly DON'T need to download anything else, (like the program above).

Comment: I had a service called "windows 10 update facilitation service" which was started with `svchost -c osrss`. I was not able stop that service, so with remove osrss.dll in system32 it was removed from the services.